# Multi-Index Lookup Mapping

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column which has a value based on 2 indices of that row. I have 2 dataframes with equivalent multi-index on the levels I'm querying (but not of equal size). For each row in the 1st dataframe, I want the value of the 2nd df that matches the row's indices.

I originally thought perhaps I could use a .loc[] and filter off the index values, but I cannot seem to get this to change the output row-by-row. If I wasn't using a dataframe object, I'd loop over the whole thing to do it.

I have tried to use the .apply() method, but I can't figure out what function to pass to it.

Creating some toy data with the same structure:

```py
#import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
np.random.seed = 1

df = pd.DataFrame({'Aircraft':np.ones(15),
                    'DC':np.append(np.repeat(['A','B'], 7), 'C'),
                    'Test':np.array([10,10,10,10,10,10,20,10,10,10,10,10,10,20,10]),
                    'Record':np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1]),
                   # There are multiple "value" columns in my data, but I have simplified here 
                   'Value':np.random.random(15)
                   }
                  )
df.set_index(['Aircraft', 'DC', 'Test', 'Record'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

v = pd.DataFrame({'Aircraft':np.ones(7),
                  'DC':np.repeat('v',7),
                  'Test':np.array([10,10,10,10,10,10,20]),
                  'Record':np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,1]),
                  'Value':np.random.random(7)
                 }
                )
v.set_index(['Aircraft', 'DC', 'Test', 'Record'], inplace=True)
v.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

```py
df['v'] = df.apply(lambda x: v.loc[df.iloc[x]])
```

Returns error for indexing on multi-index.

To set all values to a single "v" value:

```py
df['v'] = float(v.loc[(slice(None), 'v', 10, 1), 'Value'])
```

So inputs look like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Aircraft | DC | Test | Record | Value    |
|----------|----|------|--------|----------|
| 1.0      | A  | 10   | 1      | 0.847576 |
|          |    |      | 2      | 0.860720 |
|          |    |      | 3      | 0.017704 |
|          |    |      | 4      | 0.082040 |
|          |    |      | 5      | 0.583630 |
|          |    |      | 6      | 0.506363 |
|          |    | 20   | 1      | 0.844716 |
|          | B  | 10   | 1      | 0.698131 |
|          |    |      | 2      | 0.112444 |
|          |    |      | 3      | 0.718316 |
|          |    |      | 4      | 0.797613 |
|          |    |      | 5      | 0.129207 |
|          |    |      | 6      | 0.861329 |
|          |    | 20   | 1      | 0.535628 |
|          | C  | 10   | 1      | 0.121704 |
--------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------
| Aircraft | DC | Test | Record | Value    |
|----------|----|------|--------|----------|
| 1.0      | v  | 10   | 1      | 0.961791 |
|          |    |      | 2      | 0.046681 |
|          |    |      | 3      | 0.913453 |
|          |    |      | 4      | 0.495924 |
|          |    |      | 5      | 0.149950 |
|          |    |      | 6      | 0.708635 |
|          |    | 20   | 1      | 0.874841 |
--------------------------------------------
```

And after the operation, I want this:

```
| Aircraft | DC | Test | Record | Value    | v        |
|----------|----|------|--------|----------|----------|
| 1.0      | A  | 10   | 1      | 0.847576 | 0.961791 |
|          |    |      | 2      | 0.860720 | 0.046681 |
|          |    |      | 3      | 0.017704 | 0.913453 |
|          |    |      | 4      | 0.082040 | 0.495924 |
|          |    |      | 5      | 0.583630 | 0.149950 |
|          |    |      | 6      | 0.506363 | 0.708635 |
|          |    | 20   | 1      | 0.844716 | 0.874841 |
|          | B  | 10   | 1      | 0.698131 | 0.961791 |
|          |    |      | 2      | 0.112444 | 0.046681 |
|          |    |      | 3      | 0.718316 | 0.913453 |
|          |    |      | 4      | 0.797613 | 0.495924 |
|          |    |      | 5      | 0.129207 | 0.149950 |
|          |    |      | 6      | 0.861329 | 0.708635 |
|          |    | 20   | 1      | 0.535628 | 0.874841 |
|          | C  | 10   | 1      | 0.121704 | 0.961791 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**:
as you are on pandas 0.23.4, you just change `droplevel` to `reset_index` with option `drop=True`

```
df_result = (df.reset_index('DC').assign(v=v.reset_index('DC', drop=True))
               .set_index('DC', append=True)
               .reorder_levels(v.index.names))
```

**Original**:
One way is putting index `DC` of `df` to columns and using `assign` to create new column on it and `reset_index` and `reorder_index`

```
df_result = (df.reset_index('DC').assign(v=v.droplevel('DC'))
               .set_index('DC', append=True)
               .reorder_levels(v.index.names))

Out[1588]:
                            Value        v
Aircraft DC Test Record
1.0      A  10   1       0.847576  0.961791
                 2       0.860720  0.046681
                 3       0.017704  0.913453
                 4       0.082040  0.495924
                 5       0.583630  0.149950
                 6       0.506363  0.708635
            20   1       0.844716  0.874841
         B  10   1       0.698131  0.961791
                 2       0.112444  0.046681
                 3       0.718316  0.913453
                 4       0.797613  0.495924
                 5       0.129207  0.149950
                 6       0.861329  0.708635
            20   1       0.535628  0.874841
         C  10   1       0.121704  0.961791
```

Comment: In pandas 0.23.4 I'm getting an error that DataFrames do not have 'droplevel' attributes. Do I just need to update my pandas? I copied your command exactly.

Comment: @Czarified: ah, I see. check my updated. You need to use `reset_index` with `drop=True`

Comment: That worked for me with my toy dataset. I'll try it out with my full data, but I should be good to go. Thank you so much!